# How to hide sidenav in Materialize CSS when link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I have a responsive Materialize navbar with a few link items. The issue is that when a link is clicked in the sidenav, the sidenav remains visible. The only way I can hide it is to click outside the menu. Is there a way to hide the sidenav when a link is clicked?

**My code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Navbar</title>

        <!-- jQuery (must be loaded before material design javascript)-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>

        <!-- Materialize icons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <!-- Materialize CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
        <!-- Materialize JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Initialize "sidenav-trigger" using jQuery -->
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.sidenav').sidenav();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logotype</a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <div class="container">
                    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/MihkelPajunen/ouucdv0h/

Comment: this works by using `<a class="sidenav-close" ...` nowadays

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your sidebar init to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav')
        .sidenav()
        .on('click tap', 'li a', () => {
            $('.sidenav').sidenav('close');
        });
});
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/8b7q5acq/).

Comment: It does not seem to work for me. Am I missing something? https://jsfiddle.net/MihkelPajunen/ouucdv0h/1/

Comment: You need to add it after you initiate `.sidebar()`. I'll update the answer to be more clear.

Comment: Check the fiddle now. I chained sidebar initiation and the `click tap` listener.

Answer (score 14):

You can simply add  `class="sidenav-close"` to your 'ul'. This will wrap all your links. So when you click anything inside the 'ul' the sidebar will be closed.

```
    <ul class="sidenav sidenav-close" id="mobile-demo">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Much cleaner solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can target the `li` tags inside your sidenav, and with the help of Materialize function `sidebar` you can close the element with not much effort

```
$('.sidenav li').click(() => {
  $('.sidenav').sidenav('close');
})
```

[Sidenav docs](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html)

Hope this helps :)

```js
$('.sidenav li').click(() => {
  $('.sidenav').sidenav('close');
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    
    <!-- jQuery (must be loaded before material design javascript)-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Materialize icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <!-- Materialize CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!-- Materialize JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Initialize "sidenav-trigger" using jQuery -->
  <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.sidenav').sidenav();
            });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <div class="container">
            <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logotype</a>
          </div>
          <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
          <div class="container">
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
              <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're adding a `click` event listener for each `li`, rather than one listener for the entire sidebar. Also, if items are added to the menu after binding, clicking those won't close the sidebar.